# Extrinsic rotations: Angular rates vs derivative of Euler angles

Tags: rotations

If I'm dealing with extrinsic Euler angles are the Euler rates equal to the angular rates? This seems logical to me because there aren't any intermediate frames; however, I'm instead only seeing this formula for body rates

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p \\
q \\
r \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 0 & -\sin{\theta} \\
    0 & \cos{\phi} & \sin{\phi} \cos{\theta} \\
    0 & -\sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi} \cos{\theta} \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\dot{\phi} \\
\dot{\theta} \\
\dot{\psi} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

But it seems to me that for extrinsic rotations
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\omega_x \\
\omega_y \\
\omega_z \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\dot{\phi} \\
\dot{\theta} \\
\dot{\psi} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and the body rates are the angular rates rotated into the body frame (via some rotation matrix $\mathbf{T}$)

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p \\
q \\
r \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\mathbf{T}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\omega_x \\
\omega_y \\
\omega_z \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Am I incorrect? Or missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this more and you can derive the relationship between the rotational rates and Euler rates using the expression

$$\Omega = -\dot{\mathbf{T}} \mathbf{T}^{\mathrm{T}}$$

where $\Omega$ is the skew-symmetric matrix of the rotational rate $\omega$

$$\Omega = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y \\
    \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\
    -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

This is a completely general expression, it comes from the fact that

$$\mathbf{T} \mathbf{T}^{\mathrm{T}}=\mathbf{1}$$

[See a good tutorial here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.06088.pdf)